# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

The below code works inside server:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(len(ctx.author.roles))
```

Via PM i get:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Looks like can't read the roles, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How are you supposed to read roles in DMs? Roles are per-guild, you can have a different role layout on a different server.

Comment: I've to define the server?

Answer (score 1):

Think the `Member` as the "User of a Guild" and `User` as the "User of the Discord".

As the exception says: `'User' object has no attribute 'roles'` and `roles` are only a thing of the Guilds in discord; there is no such a thing called `User.roles` because there is no "Roles" in the "Discord" itself.

What you are looking for is `Member` since they are the "Users of Guilds" and only "Guild Users" can have `roles`.

So when your command is invoked in a DM (a.k.a PM), your `Member` fades away too because like i said, they are existing in Guilds and becoming non-existent in DMs.

In DMs, you are left with the `User`. It is the reason you can't do `ctx.author.roles` in DMs because `ctx.author` is a `User` and `User` object doesn't have any `role`.

You could try to get the `Member` but again `Member` is the part of a Guild so you will need a `Guild`.

Once you have the `Guild`: you can look through that `Guild`'s all `Members` and find your command author's (a.k.a `ctx.author`'s) `Member` version in that `Guild` so you can look for it's roles.

### The whole process splits into 3 parts:

- Finding the `Guild`. (It's the hardest part.)
- Finding the `Member` version of your `User` in that `Guild`.
- Finally getting the `Roles` of your `Member`.

**For the first process, i can link you:** [`User.mutual_guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.mutual_guilds), [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=text_channels#discord.Guild.text_channels), [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.TextChannel.history), [`Context.prefix`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoked_with#discord.ext.commands.Context.prefix) and [`Context.invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoked_with#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with)

**For the second process, i can link:** [`utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get) and [`User.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.id)

**And for the third process:** You can simply use [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.Member.roles)

Ta-da! Now you have all the resources to make that command working.